# Scripting Hardware Profile Creation?

Tags: scripting, hardware, profile

Is there any way to Script Hardware Profile Creation?

I have to set up a ton of Laptops with the same 3 hardware profiles (LAN, WiFi, and Modem). It takes forever and seems pointless if I could only find a script.

Powershell or .bat or any language is fine.

Comment: Is the hardware the exact same model for all the laptops?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/) to automate this.  SIKULI is an automation tool that can automate any task you can do through the GUI.  Their demo on the main page looks similar to what you're trying to do...

EDIT: The problem here would be to run the script without installing anything, e.g. from a USB drive.  Should be possible.  Obviously this is unworkable otherwise...  [This](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/128820) gives some details on how that can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have figured out that these hardawre profiles are stored on the HKLM (registry) so I should be able to manipulate them through powershell or some other script. At the very least I might just copy/paste in a predefined registry key.